# String.Format does not provide correct result for number format

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Why does the following output provide incorrect result,

```
int myNumber = 95;            
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{{{0:N}}}", myNumber ));
```

Output is `{N}` rather then `{95.00}` as expected.

Am I misunderstanding the concept of escaping `{` `}`   or doing something wrong with Number format?

Comment: what is reason for down vote any specific reason.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the ouptut given is perfectly right and your understanding is also right that `{`, `}` in `string.Format` should be escaped by `{`, `}` respectively and to format string in Number you have to use `{0:N}`.

But when you are looking for output `{95.00}` the format `{{{0:N}}}` do not work as expected, for this we should undesrstand how the above statement is interpreted,

- The first two curly brackets are escaped as we understand `{` followed by `{`,

  > prints `{` at output
- Then we have a formatting section `{0:N}}}` but compiler is confused that `}` is ending brace of `{0:N` or it is escaped brace as it is followed by `}` which result in formation of custom format `0:N}`. but rules say it should be considered as custom format, thus it is actually interpreted as containing `0:N}`
- Since neither `N` or `}` mean anything for a custom numeric format, these characters are simply written out, rather than the value of the variable referenced.

Thus we have output, `{N}`.

The detail explanation for above can be found at [string Format FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/01/14/58851.aspx)

If you are looking for output **`{95.00}`** then either use **`{{ {0:N} }}`** and it will provide `95.00` as output with space.

**EDIT** The solution by [Heinzi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465029/string-format-does-not-provide-correct-result-for-number-format/20465109#20465109) is perfectly right for the output you are expecting,

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}{1:N}{2}", "{", myNumber, "}"));
```

Answer (score 7):

Your understanding is correct: Use two braces to create a single literal brace. The problem, however, is that in the string `}}}`, the *first two braces* are interpreted as a literal brace, rather than the *second and the third*, as you intended.

In fact, your example is explicitly listed on the [corresponding MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a possible problem (highlighting by me):

> The way escaped braces are interpreted can lead to unexpected results. For example, consider the format item "{{{0:D}}}", which is intended to display an opening brace, a numeric value formatted as a decimal number, and a closing brace. However, the format item is actually interpreted in the following manner:
>
> ...
>
> - The next character ("D") would be interpreted as the Decimal standard numeric format specifier, **but the next two escaped braces ("}}") yield a single brace.**

The suggested solution is to use something like this:

```
int myNumber = 95;            
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}{1:N}{2}", "{", myNumber, "}"));
```

Comment: The answer by you is right and that was the only thing I was looking for my output, but the explanation by `dbw` is more clear that's why I am accepting his answer